# Remove every nth element from the list, if the element is not equal to an element in an other list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of strings:

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
l2 = ['a3', 'a4']
```

I need to remove every 2nd element from the `l1` if element is not equal to one of the elements from list `l2`.

so far I have tried:

```
for e1 in l1:
    i=0
    for e2 in l2:
        if e1!=e2:
            l1.remove(l1[i])
            i=i+1
```

Expected output:

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a3', 'a4, 'a5']
```

How can it be done correctly?

Comment: Are there ever duplicates in l1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a list comprehension to re-create `l1`:

```py
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
l2 = ['a3', 'a4']
l2s = set(l2)

l1 = [item for index,item in enumerate(l1) if (index & 1) == 0 or item in l2s]
print(l1)
```

Output as requested

I created `l2s` to make the `item in l2s` faster if your real `l2` is very large.

Answer (score 0):

use `l1[1::2]` to filter the list down to every second value

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
l2 = ['a3', 'a4']

for elm in l1[1::2]:
    if elm not in l2:
        l1.remove(elm)

# ['a1', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4','a5', 'a6']
l2 = ['a3', 'a4']
new_l=[j for i,j in enumerate(l1) if i%2==0 or j in l2]
print(new_l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution is finding the indexes that are valid for the conditions and then pop the items in reverse order, in order to not mess up indexes.

```
l1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6']
l2 = ['a3', 'a4']

idx_lst = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    if (i + 1) % 2 == 0 and l1[i] not in l2:
        idx_lst.append(i)

for idx in sorted(idx_lst, reverse=True):
    l1.pop(idx)

print(l1)
```